# Call the value of variable of method in another method of same class in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to access father's name in the last function(enquiry()), and the name is present in the father() function. How to access value of the name variable in the father() function?

```
class family(object):
    def __init__(self,members,surname):
        self.members=members
        self.surname=surname
    def father(self,name,occupation):
        self.name=name
        self.occupation=occupation
    def mother(self,name,occupation):
        self.name=name
        self.occupation=occupation
    def children(self,numbers):
        self.numbers=numbers
    def enquiry(self):
        print("The name of the father is "self.father(name))

family(4,'vora')
family.father('john','business')
family.enquiry()
```

Comment: Make familiy-members classes instead of functions

Comment: But can't I access the value as asked in the question?

Comment: You can, see answer below. I, for myself, would prefer more encapsulation and therefore introduce a class familyMembers.

Answer (score 0):

This code corrects your syntactic errors but you should definitely take member P i's advice because this is ugly

```
class family(object):
    def __init__(self,members,surname):
        self.members=members
        self.surname=surname
    def father(self,name,occupation):
        self.fathers_name=name
        self.occupation=occupation
    def mother(self,name,occupation):
        self.mothers_name=name
        self.occupation=occupation
    def children(self,numbers):
        self.numbers=numbers
    def enquiry(self):
        print("The name of the father is " + self.fathers_name)

f = family(4,'vora')
f.father('john','business')
f.enquiry()
```

Comment: Appreciate your help!!@kaidokuuppa

Comment: But how to use if the variable name remains same, like self.fathers_name remains as self.name. How to use that variable using the function name "father" in this context?

Comment: @karan, I think the best way to find out what happens is to try it yourself. Just replace ```self.fathers_name = name``` and ```self.mothers_name = name``` with ```self.name = name```. Using that approach your family object only has one ```name```, so the return value of enquiry depends which method you called last father or mother.